# Python3: install in virtualenv fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I tried to create Python3 virtualenv and test some Python code in it:

```
python3 -m venv tbzuploader-py3env
cd tbzuploader-py3env
. ./bin/activate
pip install -e git+https://github.com/guettli/tbzuploader.git#egg=tbzuploader
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Obtaining tbzuploader from git+https://github.com/guettli/tbzuploader.git#egg=tbzuploader
  Cloning https://github.com/guettli/tbzuploader.git to ./src/tbzuploader
Collecting requests (from tbzuploader)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future (from tbzuploader)
  Using cached future-0.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->tbzuploader)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->tbzuploader)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->tbzuploader)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->tbzuploader)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: future
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for future ... error
  Complete output from command /home/tguettler/projects/tbzuploader-py3env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4iiy_oby/future/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpukjvdwtmpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for future
  Running setup.py clean for future
Failed to build future
Installing collected packages: urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, future, tbzuploader
  Running setup.py install for future ... done
  Running setup.py develop for tbzuploader
Successfully installed certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 future-0.16.0 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 tbzuploader urllib3-1.22
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I use Python from Ubuntu 16.04:

```
===> python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By default `venv` instaled `pip` version 8. You should update it: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @AK47 you have to drop the `sudo -H` because you want to update `setuptools` in the virtualenv and not systemwide.

Comment: @AndMar yes, "pip install --upgrade pip" solved the issue. If you write your comment as answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: More usually, issue this command after creating a new virtualenv : `pip install -U pip setuptools wheel`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `venv` installed pip version 8. You should update it: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update pip version by following command.

pip install --upgrade pip

When you install python3, pip3 gets installed. And if you don't have another python installation(like python2.7) then a link is created which points pip to pip3. pip generally points to the first installation.